# Is my understanding of reflections correct?

Tags: reflection, mirroring

I'm solving the classical eight queens problem in prolog. And now I'm about to start coding the bit that removes reflections about the horizontal line. Y=4. Say if the point (3.3) is reflected, the new point would be (6,6), is that correct? Another example, (2,1) would become (7,8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones you show are not reflections but rotations.

- The reflection along the vertical center-axis (flip left-right) of a square `(x,y)` is given by `(9-x,y)` (assuming `1<=x,y<=8`).
- The reflection along the horizontal center-axis (flip top-bottom) is given by `(x,9-y)`.
- The reflection by both axes (aka rotation) is given by `(9-x,9-y)`

Comment: Spot on! Would a 90degree rotation and then do a horizontal reflection be the same as a vertical reflection?

Comment: @Algific 90degree rotation is `(y,9-x)` and after horizontal reflection becomes `(9-y,9-x)`. So no, it is not the same.